# Android after installing apk open button disabled

Tags: android

I have the problem with the open button disabled after installing an apk built by Android studio (a hybrid app built with Ionic).  All the other solutions point to a problem with the AndroidManifest and mine looks simple and normal:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="0.0.1" 
    package="com.ionicframework.test2402192">

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="16" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-feature 
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony" 
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <supports-screens 
        android:anyDensity="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/activity_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name="MainActivity" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity 
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'm using gradle version 2.1.2 with Android CompileSdkVersion 24 and buildToolsVersion 23.0.1.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to change

```
<activity 
    ...
    android:name="MainActivity"
```

to

```
<activity 
    ...
    android:name=".MainActivity"
```

According to [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm):

> The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity"). **However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period** (for example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to the package name specified in the  element.

Comment: I think you missed a period in your 'to' example.

Answer (score 0):

try uninstall your app with `adb`:

```
adb uninstall com.company.mayapp
```